# Админ панель для телеграм бота с обратной связью

Tags: python, aiogram

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать панель для админа?Админ получает сообщение от пользователей бота.
P.s Пишите по обширный т.к я в python не особо разбираюсь.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Listopad02хочу создать бота магазин для продажи игровой валюты. На базе библиотеке aiogram. Но столкнулся с проблемой отправки сообщения админу.Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать отправку смс администратору.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы отправить сообщение нужно просто сделать `bot.send_message(chat_id=айдишник_юзера_который_является_админм, text="текст")`
Пример кода

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage

from data import config

bot = Bot(token=config.BOT_TOKEN)
storage = MemoryStorage()
dp = Dispatcher(bot, storage=storage)


ADMIN_CHAT_ID = 1234567


@dp.message_handler()
async def send_to_admin(message: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(chat_id=ADMIN_CHAT_ID, text="Сообщение для админа")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```